# How to expose two ports in docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to expose 8080 and 9000 port from my docker container. I have added the EXPOSE keyword in docker file (not using docker compose file). But while trying to access the port from my browser, able to access 8080 but not able to access 9000

```
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9000
```

Command used to run the docker

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -p 8082:9000 -t <image-name>
```

While am trying to access 8081 it is working as expected but not able to access 8082. I just logged in to docker container to check the exposed port

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
```

port 9000 is exposed in 127.0.0.1. So how to change that to 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: How are you testing the access to port 9000?

Comment: Using this  URL http://localhost:8082/.. in my local browser @Maroun

Comment: What's running on that port? Should it be accessible through the browser?

Comment: It will expose a simple wsdl file..i tried loggin in to docker container and and used the curl command..then i can see the wsdl file but outside docker i can only access 8081.

Comment: It looks like your Java app is binding to localhost when it listens on port 9000. That's something you need to change in your Java program or it's configuration.

Comment: Yeah in java code the URL that using this port is hardcoded like localhost:9000/..... How to make this URL exposed in docker container ?

Comment: Things that run in Docker need to listen on the special 0.0.0.0 "everywhere" IP address (not `127.0.0.1:9000` or `localhost:9000`), or they won't be accessible from outside their own containers.  You can't change this with Docker-level configuration; "expose" as a Docker verb means almost nothing in the modern networking setup.